# Cannot place anchor tag on same line as text input

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am unable to place an anchor tag next to a text input:

```js
// Having this does not make a difference
//$( "#id_test" ).textinput( "option", "wrapperClass", "input-width" );
```

```css
.input-width {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui-field-contain">
  <input id="id_test" maxlength="7" name="test" placeholder="Enter input" type="text" />
  <a href="#some-help" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-info" title="Learn more">Learn more</a>
  <div data-role="popup" id="some-help">
    <p>Some help here</p>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Having this instead of the above a and div tags makes no difference -->
  <!-- <a href=#>Learn more</a> --> 
</div>
```

Even if the JS code is uncommented and the field width is 200px, the anchor tag is still on the next line.  It also does not matter if I don't have the anchor tag and div combination there and instead have the uncommented anchor tag included.

Comment: Use jQM grid system.

Comment: The grid system results in dividing the entire page/containing div into halfs, thirds, etc.

Comment: No, it doesn't divide the whole page/container. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/grids/

Comment: If I used a grid for this, then I'd have one row where half of the width contains the text input and the other half has just the icon.  With DaniP's solution, the text input spans the maximum width of the screen up to the anchor tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery mobile creates a wrapper around the `input` elements, so you need to change the style of those containers to remove the *block* behavior:

```css
.ui-input-text {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui-field-contain">
  <input id="id_test" maxlength="7" name="test" placeholder="Enter input" type="text" />
  <a href="#some-help" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-info" title="Learn more">Learn more</a>
  <div data-role="popup" id="some-help">
    <p>Some help here</p>
  </div>
```

---

#### Update

Using `flexbox` you can make the `input` take all available space like this:

<sub>**Note you don't need the !important it's just here the snippet that requires it**</sub>

```css
.ui-field-contain {
  display:flex !important;
}
.ui-input-text {
  flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui-field-contain">
  <input id="id_test" maxlength="7" name="test" placeholder="Enter input" type="text" />
  <a href="#some-help" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-info" title="Learn more">Learn more</a>
  <div data-role="popup" id="some-help">
    <p>Some help here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-field-contain">
  <input id="id_test" maxlength="7" name="test" placeholder="Enter input" type="text" />
  <a href="#some-help" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-info" title="Learn more">Learn more</a>
  <div data-role="popup" id="some-help">
    <p>Some help here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works in Chrome, but the input field does not span the maximum width possible.  To make it consistent with the other text fields in my form, it would be nice if it could span the maximum width.  On Firefox the anchor tag is not aligned with the the input field.

Comment: @user2233706 just to clarify `ui-field-contain` is the parent of just this input ?

Comment: I added that div to just that input group only because I thought it was needed to have the two elements on the same line.  I don't need it if I don't have to have it.

Comment: Note that flex isn't supported by all mobile browsers.

Comment: @Omar thx for the note, actually for mobile the only one I can see isn't supported is Opera12 http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox ... The problem is with IE

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.controlgroup-textinput {
  border-width: 1px !important;
  padding: .25em 0 !important;
  border-bottom-style: solid !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
.controlgroup-textinput.ui-input-text {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
.controlgroup-textinput input {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"><h2>Header</h2></div> 
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
      <input id="test" name="test" type="text" maxlength="7" placeholder="Enter input" data-wrapper-class="controlgroup-textinput ui-btn">
      <a href="#some-help" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-info" title="Learn more">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h2>Footer</h2></div>    
  <div data-role="popup" id="some-help">
    <p>Some help here</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```